# O que seria DSN?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia

Sempre que vejo alguém preparando alguma configuração para banco de dados, vejo aparecendo o termo DSN.

Vejo acontecendo isso nos parâmetros do `PDO` (classe para conectar com Banco de dados) do PHP.

Exemplo:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test';

$pdo = new PDO($dsn);
```

Esse termo DSN é alguma nomenclatura usada para banco de dados? O que significa esse termo?

Comment: `DSN` Data Source Name

Answer (score 12, accepted):

DSN é Data Source Name, genericamente o termo define as configurações (ip, usuário, nome do recurso, porta, protocolo etc) necessárias para o acesso a uma fonte de dados. No caso da pergunta, é um banco de dados. Outro exemplo seria o LDAP.

Answer (score 5):

Não é uma nomenclatura, DSN é a sigla em inglês para *Data Source Name* (Nome de Fonte de Dados, em português) que contém as informações necessárias para se conectar ao banco de dados.  Essas informações podem ser: o tipo e nome do banco de dados, o usuário, senha, driver, diretório, entre outras informações que serão utilizadas para a conexão.

Na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.construct.php) você encontra mais explicações e exemplo sobre ele.